# Php script not working in Safari only (online only - it works locally for testing)

Tags: php, debugging, safari

This script works in all browsers but not Apple Mac or Windows Safari. It works on same machines in Chrome. It works in other browsers. iOS no problem. It works in localhost too with Safari - just not on line! - Mac Safari: login happens and the user stays briefly (milliseconds) on index.php but immediately gets sent back to login page...

login_do.php below...

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        require ('includes/connect_db.php');
        require ('login_tools.php');
        list ($check,$data)=validate($con,$_POST['username'],$_POST['pass']);
        if ($check)
            {session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_id']=$data['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['username']=$data['username'];
                $_SESSION['admin']=$data['admin'];
                load ('index.php');
            }
        else {$errors=$data;}
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
include ('login.php');
?>
```

Why?

This is the login.php that POSTs to the above script.

```
<?php
$page_title='Login';
include ('includes/header.html');?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handover.css">
<?php 
if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors))
{
echo'<p id="err_msg">Oops! There was a problem:<br>';
foreach ($errors as $msg)
{
echo "- $msg<br>";
}
echo 'Please try again or <a href="help.php">Ask for help</a></p>';
}
?>
<div id="middler">
<h2>
<form action="login_do.php" method="POST">
<p>
User name: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
<p>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"></p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="Login"value="Login"></p>
</form>

</div>
<?php 
include ('includes/logoutfooter.html')?>
```

The index.php that the login lands on briefly...

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $screenname=$_SESSION['username'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
    $admincheck=$_SESSION['admin'];
}

else {$url = 'login.php';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';}
?>
```

And finally: login_tools.php

```
<?php
function load ($page = 'login.php')
{
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$url=rtrim($url,'/\\');
$url.='/'.$page;
header("Location: $url");
exit();
}
function validate($con,$email='' , $pwd = '')
{
$errors=array();
if (empty($email))
{$errors[]='Enter your user name.';}
else
{$e=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($email));}
if (empty($pwd))
{$errors[]='Enter your password.';}
else
{$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($pwd));}

if (empty($errors))
{
$q="SELECT user_id, username, admin
FROM DPLA.users
WHERE username='$e'
AND password='$p'";
$r=mysqli_query($con, $q);
if (@mysqli_num_rows($r)==1)
{$row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return array(true,$row);
}
else
{$errors[]='username and password not found.';}
}
return array(false, $errors);
}
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, so its output won't be affected by the browser. It has to be a problem with the way the browser is POSTing the username and pass.

Comment: What have you done to debug it? Have you tried putting `echo` statements at different places in the script, to see which `if` statements are failing?

Comment: How is this script called? Is it normal form submission, or AJAX? Please show the client-side code. What does `var_dump($_POST)` show in the script?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang That's what I thought! But, the only variable is the browser! I'm stumped.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @Barmar - I've editied the question again... it works in Safari locally (localhost) but not online. It does seem to manage to log in but gets booted out immediately. var_dump($_SESSION) in index.php shows the variables being passed through locally... I just can't see why it should be different online.

Comment: I guess you don't really want my help, because I've asked twice for you to add the output of `var_dump($_POST)` to the question and you haven't done it.

Comment: @Barmar hey, I do want your help! But the problem has altered slightly in that I can see it does log in but throws me out again quickly. So, the $_POST is being passed as expected. It allows the retrieval of the correct data from the DB as demonstrated by the var_dump($_SESSION). I got to that because I was following your suggestion originally. Sorry, if you're irritated - but I thought I was using your help!

Comment: What does `load('index.php')` do?

Comment: @Barmar Do you mean login.php?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, see what you mean. It's from a function in an include.

Comment: Does it do a redirect? Are you sure the redirect is actually happening? If not, `include ('login.php')` at the end of the script will put you back in the login page.

Comment: @Barmar I've added the login_tools.php to the question... could it be that the header call isn't liked by Safari? Is there something in the way Safari handles meta stuff perhaps?

Comment: Check your PHP log to make sure you're not getting the warning "Headers already sent".

Comment: @Barmar Not sure how! There's no error locally.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of all the scripts.

Comment: @Barmar Once again, thanks for your help. I've managed to find (by filming the screen and then inserting some code) that in Safari the screenname and admincheck variables aren't set. In all other browsers they are. So - in login.php it executes the else statement in Safari but not in other browsers. How is that possible?

Comment: Could you be blocking cookies in Safari? Session variables depend on cookies.

Comment: @Barmar Bingo! Privacy settings. You have set Block Cookies to 'never'. Safari sees this as 'third party or advertising' - how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clause that emits the meta-refresh that redirects to `login.php` is only attached to the `$_SESSION['admin']` check. So any non-admin will be redirected back, even if `$_SESSION['username']` is set. Change it to:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $screenname=$_SESSION['username'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    {
        $admincheck=$_SESSION['admin'];
    }
} else {
    $url = 'login.php';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: Man! I was willing that to work... but no good, just the same.